# Using ES6 modules in the browser

Tags: javascript, import, module, ecmascript-6, export

I am trying to export and import objects in the browser using ES6 modules.

I have tried

```
import { options } from 'options';
```

but I get the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import`.

Then I tried transpiling it, but now I receive the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`.

Is it not possible to use modules in the browser?

Comment: You need webpack or browserify or something that bundles for the browser.

Comment: I am using `babel-standalone` to transpile it. Shouldn't it work like webpack and browserify?

Comment: ES6 Modules are not implemented yet... [https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

Comment: The future is soon: http://caniuse.com/#search=modules

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into http://jspm.io/ it's based on system.js.

Hope that helps..